# Ctrl + ~ hotkey in Swing

Tags: java, swing

Do you know if it is possible to create a hotkey or keystroke composed of `Ctrl + ~` in Swing?

I tried this:

```
menus[1].addItem("View Posting", '~','~', false, true);
```

in the `createMenus` method, but it doesn't trigger if I type `Ctrl + ~`, only if I click on the menu (calling the actionPerformed method).
Also in the menu I added the item it shows "Ctrl+Unknown KeyCode: 0x7e" intead of "Ctrl+~" as the shortcut.

Comment: This isn't about Java, it's about whatever library you're using. Please be more specific. Is this Swing? JavaFX? Something else? Aside from that, good first question!

Comment: Hello!, it is Swing

Comment: What is the type of the elements of the `menus` array?  It can’t be Swing’s [JMenu](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JMenu.html), since that class doesn’t have an `addItem` method.

Comment: I declared the menus array as: menus = new EMenu[5];

Comment: What is the `import` statement for the EMenu type?

Comment: Rather than adding chunks of information per @VGR's questions, why not create and post a proper [mcve]? i.e. a minimal code with a `JMenu`, an `ActionListener` that prints the `KeyCode`, this way will be easier and faster for us to help you, right now we don't know what an `EMenu` is.